# Add .ipa file as library in a xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I created a project and generated its .ipa file. Now I want to link this .ipa file as library into other project.
 Is it possible to do it? If yes how can I achieve this?
Please help me..

Comment: As library means . Didn't get your question

Answer (score 1):

an .ipa file as a library?  no... you can't do that.  An .ipa file is essentially a .zip file containing the application binary and resources (compressed or not). There's nothing exposed that whatever you're trying to do can hook into.

Use a static `.a` library or a dynamic `.dylib` or a framework to expose functionality from another project for use somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can never add a .ipa into a project. If you want to use some functionality from the project then create a static library (.a) out of the code and you can use it in any project. Or if you want you can create a framework .

EDITED : Use this URL. Its a nice tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Comment: Yeas. Sneha is right. You can never add a .ipa into a project.